# BinaryFormatter doesn't deserialize objects on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, serialization

I've this interfaces and classes (you can take a look on [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bPYdJU) to see all related code as compilable). I'm only going to provide minimal code in order to describe the problem (non-compilable code):

```
interface IViz<T> : ISerializable {
    IEnumerable<SelectedValue> SelectedValues { get; }
};

[Serializable]
abstract class GroupViz<T, TIn, TOut> : IViz<T> {
    public IEnumerable<SelectedValue> SelectedValues
    {
        get { return selectedValues.Cast<SelectedValue>(); }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class EntityValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey> : ValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey>
```

On first interface (`IViz`) I've declared a property `IEnumerable<SelectedValue> SelectedValues` where are stored each `SelectedValue` objects.

`SelectedValue` has two implementations (a generic and a non-generic ones):

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class SelectedValue : ISerializable
{
    public SelectedValue(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Configuration.SerializationTemplatesEnum serializationTemplateEnum = (Configuration.SerializationTemplatesEnum)context.Context;

        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
        {
            switch (serializationTemplateEnum)
            {
                case Configuration.SerializationTemplatesEnum.QUERY:
                    switch (entry.Name)
                    {
                        case "Value":
                            Value = entry.Value;
                            break;

                        case "Operator":
                            Operator = (VizOperatorEnum)entry.Value;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case Configuration.SerializationTemplatesEnum.TEMPLATE:
                    break;

            }

        }

    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SelectedValue<T> : SelectedValue, ISerializable
{
    public SelectedValue(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm using a `BinaryFormatter` in order to serialize them, and they (`SelectedValue` objects on `IViz.SelectValues` property) are serialized on file.

However, when I'm trying to deserialize them, they are not loaded. I've added a breakpoint on `SelectedValue(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` constructor, and it's not reached.

I've also tried to add a `set;` implementation on `IViz.SelectedValues` property and I've also tried to set the property as an `IList` instead of `IEnumerable`. However the result is the same: My `SelectedValue` objects aren't deserialized.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've tried to add every minimal de/serialization related code in order to be able to fit your request. It's on [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bPYdJU).

Comment: OK, there's a problem with how you are deserializing `SelectedValues` in `EntityValueGroupViz`, however the test code in [your fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bPYdJU) doesn't construct and store an instance of this type, it constructs an instance of `EntityQueryContext<TEntity>`.  There seems to be a `IList<IViz<T>> vizs` inside the base class but it's not public and never populated.

Comment: Thanks. As far I'm been able to figure out, you are suggesting that deserialization works, nevertheless, I've not reach my `vizs`'s content anywhere (I think it's probably a code miswritting). I'd like to suggest to ask about why any `SelectedValue(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` constructor is reached on deserialization when `SelectedValue.GetObjectData()` is reached on serialization. I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your problem by constructing an instance of `EntityValueGroupViz<BOEntity, BOEntity>`, adding a `SelectedValue<BOEntity>(new BOEntity(), "hello")` to it, and serializing.  See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0XfMAa) for an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

However, simply to get to the point of reproducing the problem, I had to:

- Mark `BOEntity` as `[Serializable]`.
- Add default and streaming constructors to `GroupViz<T, TIn, TOut>` and `ValueGroupViz<T, TIn>`.
- Allocate the `selectedValues` list inside `GroupViz<T, TIn, TOut>` inside the constructors.
- Add a default constructor to `EntityValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey>`.

Once those preliminary fixes are made, the problem becomes apparent in the streaming constructor for `EntityValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey>`:

```
    protected EntityValueGroupViz(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
        {
            switch (entry.Name)
            {
                case "SelectedValues":
                    foreach (SelectedValue sv in (IEnumerable<SelectedValue>)entry.Value)
                        this.Value(sv);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

At the time this is called, the `(IEnumerable<SelectedValue>)entry.Value` has null entries.  But, why is that?  `BinaryFormatter` is a graph serializer.  Rather than objects being stored in a pure tree, they are assigned temporary object ids and stored as they are encountered.  When an object is deserialized, it is not guaranteed that all referenced objects have been previously deserialized.  Thus it's possible the entries in your `entry.Value` have not been filled in yet at the time the streaming constructor is called.  As confirmation, Microsoft [writes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)

> Objects are reconstructed from the inside out, and calling methods during deserialization can have undesirable side effects, since the methods called might refer to object references that have not been deserialized by the time the call is made.

Iterating through a `List<T>` does in fact involve calling methods on it.

So, how to deal with this?  There are a couple possible workarounds:

1. Implement [`IDeserializationCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) on `EntityValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey>`, temporarily cache the `entry.Value` in the streaming constructor, and later add it to the base class in `IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization()`:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   public class EntityValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey> : ValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey>, IDeserializationCallback
   {
       IEnumerable<SelectedValue> cachedEntry;

       // Added necessary default constructor.
       public EntityValueGroupViz() : base() { }

       protected EntityValueGroupViz(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
       {
           foreach (SerializationEntry entry in info)
           {
               switch (entry.Name)
               {
                   case "SelectedValues":
                       cachedEntry = (IEnumerable<SelectedValue>)entry.Value;
                       break;
               }
           }
       }

       public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       {
           info.AddValue("SelectedValues", SelectedValues);
       }

       #region IDeserializationCallback Members

       public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
       {
           if (cachedEntry != null)
           {
               foreach (SelectedValue sv in cachedEntry)
                   this.Value(sv);
               cachedEntry = null;
           }
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```

   Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aZVdvB).
2. Simply serialize the list of selected values in the base class where the field exists.  `BinaryFormatter` serialization streams are completely typed, so the `selectedValues` field can be stored there even if the base class does not know the subtypes inside the collection:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   public abstract class GroupViz<T, TIn, TOut> : IViz<T>
   {
       // Added necessary default and streaming constructors
       public GroupViz()
       {
           selectedValues = new List<SelectedValue>();
       }

       protected GroupViz(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       {
           selectedValues = (IList<SelectedValue>)info.GetValue("SelectedValues", typeof(IList<SelectedValue>));
       }

       // Allocated the list
       private IList<SelectedValue> selectedValues;

       public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       {
           info.AddValue("SelectedValues", selectedValues);
       }

       public IEnumerable<SelectedValue> SelectedValues
       {
           get { return selectedValues.Cast<SelectedValue>(); }
       }

       public void Value(SelectedValue @value)
       {
           this.AddValue(@value.Value, @value.Operator);
       }

       private void AddValue(object @value, object vizOperator)
       {
           SelectedValue<TOut> selectedValue = new SelectedValue<TOut>((TOut)value, vizOperator);
           if (!this.selectedValues.Any(sv => sv.Equals(selectedValue)))
               this.selectedValues.Add(selectedValue);
       }
   }

   public abstract class ValueGroupViz<T, TIn> : GroupViz<T, TIn, TIn>
   {
       // Added necessary default and streaming constructors
       public ValueGroupViz() : base() { }

       protected ValueGroupViz(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class EntityValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey> : ValueGroupViz<TEntity, TKey>
   {
       // Added necessary default constructor.
       public EntityValueGroupViz() : base() { }

       protected EntityValueGroupViz(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
   }
   ```

   As you can see, this solution is simpler, and thus recommended.

   Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qLg7tO).

Comment: Dear. I've tried to use second option you've writen down. Unhopefully it keeps failing. I mean, as you have guessed: when `case "SelectedValues": foreach (SelectedValue sv in (IEnumerable<SelectedValue>)entry.Value) this.Value(sv);` is reached `sv is null`. I've added a default public constructor on `GroupViz`, `ValueGroupViz` and on `EntityValueGroupViz`. I've just realized `SelectedValue` has no a default empty constructor...

Comment: @Jordi - in the second option that code is completely removed.  Instead in the base class there is `selectedValues = (IList<SelectedValue>)info.GetValue("SelectedValues", typeof(IList<SelectedValue>));`